# Issues with button widgets on flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

[image: That is my code]

So I am new to flutter and I was trying to tie a function to button widgets on flutter. It did not work and I honestly do not know why. I put my code in the picture and I would also copy and paste the code below.

```
//ignore_for_file: deprecated_member_use

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(FirstApp());

class FirstApp extends StatelessWidget {
  void answerQuestion(){
    print ('Question answered!');
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('My First App'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Text('The question!'),
            ElevatedButton(child: Text('Answer 1'), onPressed: answerQuestion),
            ElevatedButton(child: Text('Answer 2'), onPressed: answerQuestion),
            ElevatedButton(child: Text('Answer 3'), onPressed: answerQuestion),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes in your folder test, click in the error and change the name MyApp to FirstApp.

[image]